# How to inject Environment into ExecutionCondition

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test, junit5-extension-model

I'm writing unit tests and trying to use `ExecutionCondition` for enabling the test only when specific profile activated exclusively.

I created my `ExecutionCondition`.

```
class EnabledWithH2ExclusiveExecutionCondition implements ExecutionCondition {

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(
            final ExtensionContext context) {
        // check the environment
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
}
```

But the `environment` is not injected.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `ExecutionCondition` is created by JUnit5 itself using reflection .It is not managed by Spring and so the `@Autowired` will not work.

You can call `SpringExtension.getApplicationContext()` to get Spring Context and then get the `Environment` from it :

```
@Override
public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(final ExtensionContext context){
          Environment env = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context).getEnvironment();
        // check the environment
}
```

Comment: That's partially true, and that approach of course works. Note, however, that one may alternatively choose the approach mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237046/junit-5-inject-spring-components-to-custom-testtemplateinvocationcontextprovide

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know that before