# How to inject Spring beans into a JUnit Jupiter ExecutionCondition

Tags: java, spring, junit5, spring-annotations

I have custom Interface "Platform" with @ExtendWith annotation and Class which implements ExecutionCondition.

```
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@ExtendWith(PlatformExecutionCondition.class)
public @interface Platform {

    MobilePlatform[] value();

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlatformExecutionCondition implements ExecutionCondition {

    private final EmulatorConfigProperties emulatorConfigProperties;

    private final PlatformAnnotationManager platformAnnotationManager;

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext   extensionContext) {
        MobilePlatform platform =       MobilePlatform.getByName(emulatorConfigProperties.getPlatformName());
        if (platform == null) {
            return disabled("Mobile platform is not specified");
        }
        if (extensionContext.getTestMethod().isEmpty()) {
            return enabled("Test class execution enabled");
        }

        Set<MobilePlatform> mobilePlatforms = platformAnnotationManager.getTestMobilePlatforms(extensionContext);
        if (mobilePlatforms.contains(platform)) {
            return enabled(format("{0} mobile platform is available for testing", platform.getName()));
        } else {
            return disabled(format("{0} mobile platform is not available for testing",   platform.getName()));
        }
    }
 }
```

While running the test, I catch an error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mob.market3b.platform.execution.PlatformExecutionCondition.<init>()
If I remove the annotation, the test runs without errors, but then the evaluateExecutionCondition method is not in use. How can I use @ExtendWith annotation with Spring?

Comment: JUnit 5 requires extensions to have no-argument constructors when they are registered with `@ExtendWith`. See [`Extension`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/Extension.html) for details. The [`@RequiredArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) annotation on your class means you don't have a no-argument constructor. Are you asking how to inject dependencies into a JUnit extension?

Comment: Yes! I tried instead of RequiredArgsConstructor to use AllArgsConstructor and
NoArgsConstructor  - then i have such error: Failed to evaluate condition [com.mob.market3b.platform.execution.PlatformExecutionCondition]: Cannot invoke "com.mob.market3b.config.EmulatorConfigProperties.getPlatformName()" because "this.emulatorConfigProperties" is null. What can i do @Slaw?

Answer (score 3):

As [@slaw mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77467202/how-to-use-extendwith-annotation-on-class-in-spring-tests#comment136570423_77467202), your `PlatformExecutionCondition` must have a default no-args constructor.

Consequently, the fields in `PlatformExecutionCondition` cannot be `final`.

Although you could create an instance of `PlatformExecutionCondition` as a bean in your `ApplicationContext` and have that injected into a field in the test class annotated with `@Autowired` and `@RegisterExtension` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251190/388980), the simplest way to access beans from the `ApplicationContext` within a custom JUnit Jupiter extension is to retrieve them manually from the `ApplicationContext` -- for example via `getBean(<bean type>)`.

You can access the application context within your `PlatformExecutionCondition` via `org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(ExtensionContext)`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56922657/388980

##### WARNING

Please note that accessing the `ApplicationContext` (or beans within the application context) in an `ExecutionCondition` implementation is generally not recommended since your `ExecutionCondition` may then effectively force the creation of an `ApplicationContext` that would otherwise not be used (if the `ExecutionCondition` ends up disabling the test). See the documentation for [`@DisabledIf(loadContext)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/DisabledIf.html#loadContext()) for details.

##### Side Note

Spring's `@EnabledIf` and `@DisabledIf` annotations may be an easier alternative to implementing your own `ExecutionCondition`.